# Making a Web Banner Responsive

Tags: jquery, html, css, scaling, responsive

So I created a web banner using `divs` and jquery. I was wondering if there was a way to make it more responsive. It uses % and does scale but as a default the letters "HF" are drawn in a different color. So if it scales the word HF and the banner `height` changes. Is there a solution to make it more scalable. Right now it only works well with 2736 x 1824.

I don't think the code will help but if you want it please ask,
Thanks!

[**JSFiddle showing the problem**](https://jsfiddle.net/w9kusqzx/).

My JS:

```
$(function() {
    $('body').hide().fadeIn('slow');
    $('.squareColour').hover(

        function(){
            $(this).animate({'backgroundColor': 'rgb(207,3,114)'},400);
        },
        function(){
            $(this).animate({'backgroundColor': 'rgb(78,76,80)'},400);
        }

    );
    $('.squareColourHF').hover(

        function(){
            $(this).animate({'backgroundColor': 'rgb(202,212,0)'},400);
        },
        function(){
            $(this).animate({'backgroundColor': 'rgb(253,198,0)'},400);
        }

    );
});
```

My CSS:

```
.squareColour{
    width: 2%;
    padding-top: 2%;
    background: rgba(0, 148, 170, 0.53);
    margin-left: 0.001%;
    margin-right: 0.001%;
    margin-top: 0.001%;
    margin-bottom: 0.001%;
    border-radius: 15%;
    display: inline-block;
}
.squareColourHF{
    width: 2%;
    padding-top: 2%;
    background: rgba(207,3,114,0.53);
    margin-left: 0.001%;
    margin-right: 0.001%;
    margin-top: 0.001%;
    margin-bottom: 0.001%;
    border-radius: 15%;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: Can you provide a JSFiddle?

Comment: I have no idea what you are talking about and whats your problem. You should consider rewriting your question using an MCVE http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I thing code will help.

Comment: Here you go: https://jsfiddle.net/w9kusqzx/

Comment: It scales to the letters HF when ran at 2736 x 1824.

Comment: add each row of squares into a div. that will then prevent them from wrapping to the next line

Comment: this only works when scaling outwards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this will a combination of flexbox, viewport units and rows.

```
.squareColour{
    width: 2vw;
    padding-top: 2vw;
    background: rgba(0, 148, 170, 0.53);
    border-radius: 15%;
}
.squareColourHF{
    width: 2vw;
    padding-top: 2vw;
    background: rgba(207,3,114,0.53);
    border-radius: 15%;
}



.row {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  margin: .2vw;
```

}

```css
.squareColour {
  width: 2vw;
  padding-top: 2vw;
  background: rgba(0, 148, 170, 0.53);
  border-radius: 15%;
}
.squareColourHF {
  width: 2vw;
  padding-top: 2vw;
  background: rgba(207, 3, 114, 0.53);
  border-radius: 15%;
}
.row {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  margin: .2vw;
}
```

```html
<div id="bannerTop">
  <div class="row row1">
    <div class="squareColour">
    </div>
    <div class="squareColour">
    </div>
    <div class="squareColour">
    </div>
    <div class="squareColour">
    </div>
    <div class="squareColour">
    </div>

    <div class="squareColour">
    </div>
    <div class="squareColour">
    </div>
    <div class="squareColour">
    </div>
    <div class="squareColour">
    </div>
    <div class="squareColour">
    </div>


    <div class="squareColour">
    </div>
    <div class="squareColour">
    </div>
    <div class="squareColour">
    </div>
    <div class="squareColour">
    </div>
    <div class="squareColourHF">
    </div>


    <div class="squareColourHF">
    </div>
    <div class="squareColour">
    </div>
    <div class="squareColour">
    </div>
    <div class="squareColourHF">
    </div>
    <div class="squareColourHF">
    </div>


    <div class="squareColour">
    </div>
    <div class="squareColour">
    </div>
    <div class="squareColourHF">
    </div>
    <div class="squareColourHF">
    </div>
    <div class="squareColourHF">
    </div>


    <div class="squareColourHF">
    </div>
    <div class="squareColourHF">
    </div>
    <div class="squareColour">
    </div>
    <div class="squareColour">
    </div>
    <div class="squareColour">
    </div>


    <div class="squareColour">
    </div>
    <div class="squareColour">
    </div>
    <div class="squareColour">
    </div>
    <div class="squareColour">
    </div>
    <div class="squareColour ">
    </div>


    <div class="squareColour">
    </div>
    <div class="squareColour">
    </div>
    <div class="squareColour">
    </div>
    <div class="squareColour">
    </div>
    <div class="squareColour">
    </div>

    <div class="squareColour">
    </div>
    <div class="squareColour ">
    </div>
    <div class="squareColour">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row row2">
    <div class="squareColour">
    </div>
    <div class="squareColour">
    </div>
    <div class="squareColour">
    </div>
    <div class="squareColour">
    </div>
    <div class="squareColour">
    </div>

    <div class="squareColour">
    </div>
    <div class="squareColour">
    </div>
    <div class="squareColour">
    </div>
    <div class="squareColour">
    </div>
    <div class="squareColour">
    </div>


    <div class="squareColour">
    </div>
    <div class="squareColour">
    </div>
    <div class="squareColour">
    </div>
    <div class="squareColour">
    </div>
    <div class="squareColourHF">
    </div>


    <div class="squareColourHF">
    </div>
    <div class="squareColour">
    </div>
    <div class="squareColour">
    </div>
    <div class="squareColourHF">
    </div>
    <div class="squareColourHF">
    </div>


    <div class="squareColour">
    </div>
    <div class="squareColour">
    </div>
    <div class="squareColourHF">
    </div>
    <div class="squareColourHF">
    </div>
    <div class="squareColourHF">
    </div>


    <div class="squareColourHF">
    </div>
    <div class="squareColourHF">
    </div>
    <div class="squareColour">
    </div>
    <div class="squareColour">
    </div>
    <div class="squareColour">
    </div>


    <div class="squareColour">
    </div>
    <div class="squareColour">
    </div>
    <div class="squareColour">
    </div>
    <div class="squareColour">
    </div>
    <div class="squareColour ">
    </div>


    <div class="squareColour">
    </div>
    <div class="squareColour">
    </div>
    <div class="squareColour">
    </div>
    <div class="squareColour">
    </div>
    <div class="squareColour">
    </div>

    <div class="squareColour">
    </div>
    <div class="squareColour ">
    </div>
    <div class="squareColour">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row row3">
    <div class="squareColour">
    </div>
    <div class="squareColour">
    </div>
    <div class="squareColour">
    </div>
    <div class="squareColour">
    </div>
    <div class="squareColour">
    </div>

    <div class="squareColour">
    </div>
    <div class="squareColour">
    </div>
    <div class="squareColour">
    </div>
    <div class="squareColour">
    </div>
    <div class="squareColour">
    </div>


    <div class="squareColour">
    </div>
    <div class="squareColour">
    </div>
    <div class="squareColour">
    </div>
    <div class="squareColour">
    </div>
    <div class="squareColourHF">
    </div>


    <div class="squareColourHF">
    </div>
    <div class="squareColour">
    </div>
    <div class="squareColour">
    </div>
    <div class="squareColourHF">
    </div>
    <div class="squareColourHF">
    </div>


    <div class="squareColour">
    </div>
    <div class="squareColour">
    </div>
    <div class="squareColourHF">
    </div>
    <div class="squareColourHF">
    </div>
    <div class="squareColour">
    </div>


    <div class="squareColour">
    </div>
    <div class="squareColour">
    </div>
    <div class="squareColour">
    </div>
    <div class="squareColour">
    </div>
    <div class="squareColour">
    </div>


    <div class="squareColour">
    </div>
    <div class="squareColour">
    </div>
    <div class="squareColour">
    </div>
    <div class="squareColour">
    </div>
    <div class="squareColour ">
    </div>


    <div class="squareColour">
    </div>
    <div class="squareColour">
    </div>
    <div class="squareColour">
    </div>
    <div class="squareColour">
    </div>
    <div class="squareColour">
    </div>

    <div class="squareColour">
    </div>
    <div class="squareColour ">
    </div>
    <div class="squareColour">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row row4">
    <div class="squareColour">
    </div>
    <div class="squareColour">
    </div>
    <div class="squareColour">
    </div>
    <div class="squareColour">
    </div>
    <div class="squareColour">
    </div>

    <div class="squareColour">
    </div>
    <div class="squareColour">
    </div>
    <div class="squareColour">
    </div>
    <div class="squareColour">
    </div>
    <div class="squareColour">
    </div>


    <div class="squareColour">
    </div>
    <div class="squareColour">
    </div>
    <div class="squareColour">
    </div>
    <div class="squareColour">
    </div>
    <div class="squareColourHF">
    </div>


    <div class="squareColourHF">
    </div>
    <div class="squareColourHF">
    </div>
    <div class="squareColourHF">
    </div>
    <div class="squareColourHF">
    </div>
    <div class="squareColourHF">
    </div>


    <div class="squareColour">
    </div>
    <div class="squareColour">
    </div>
    <div class="squareColourHF">
    </div>
    <div class="squareColourHF">
    </div>
    <div class="squareColourHF">
    </div>


    <div class="squareColourHF">
    </div>
    <div class="squareColourHF">
    </div>
    <div class="squareColour">
    </div>
    <div class="squareColour">
    </div>
    <div class="squareColour">
    </div>


    <div class="squareColour">
    </div>
    <div class="squareColour">
    </div>
    <div class="squareColour">
    </div>
    <div class="squareColour">
    </div>
    <div class="squareColour ">
    </div>


    <div class="squareColour">
    </div>
    <div class="squareColour">
    </div>
    <div class="squareColour">
    </div>
    <div class="squareColour">
    </div>
    <div class="squareColour">
    </div>

    <div class="squareColour">
    </div>
    <div class="squareColour ">
    </div>
    <div class="squareColour">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row row5">
    <div class="squareColour">
    </div>
    <div class="squareColour">
    </div>
    <div class="squareColour">
    </div>
    <div class="squareColour">
    </div>
    <div class="squareColour">
    </div>

    <div class="squareColour">
    </div>
    <div class="squareColour">
    </div>
    <div class="squareColour">
    </div>
    <div class="squareColour">
    </div>
    <div class="squareColour">
    </div>


    <div class="squareColour">
    </div>
    <div class="squareColour">
    </div>
    <div class="squareColour">
    </div>
    <div class="squareColour">
    </div>
    <div class="squareColourHF">
    </div>


    <div class="squareColourHF">
    </div>
    <div class="squareColour">
    </div>
    <div class="squareColour">
    </div>
    <div class="squareColourHF">
    </div>
    <div class="squareColourHF">
    </div>


    <div class="squareColour">
    </div>
    <div class="squareColour">
    </div>
    <div class="squareColourHF">
    </div>
    <div class="squareColourHF">
    </div>
    <div class="squareColourHF">
    </div>


    <div class="squareColourHF">
    </div>
    <div class="squareColourHF">
    </div>
    <div class="squareColour">
    </div>
    <div class="squareColour">
    </div>
    <div class="squareColour">
    </div>


    <div class="squareColour">
    </div>
    <div class="squareColour">
    </div>
    <div class="squareColour">
    </div>
    <div class="squareColour">
    </div>
    <div class="squareColour ">
    </div>


    <div class="squareColour">
    </div>
    <div class="squareColour">
    </div>
    <div class="squareColour">
    </div>
    <div class="squareColour">
    </div>
    <div class="squareColour">
    </div>

    <div class="squareColour">
    </div>
    <div class="squareColour ">
    </div>
    <div class="squareColour">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row row6">
    <div class="squareColour">
    </div>
    <div class="squareColour">
    </div>
    <div class="squareColour">
    </div>
    <div class="squareColour">
    </div>
    <div class="squareColour">
    </div>

    <div class="squareColour">
    </div>
    <div class="squareColour">
    </div>
    <div class="squareColour">
    </div>
    <div class="squareColour">
    </div>
    <div class="squareColour">
    </div>


    <div class="squareColour">
    </div>
    <div class="squareColour">
    </div>
    <div class="squareColour">
    </div>
    <div class="squareColour">
    </div>
    <div class="squareColourHF">
    </div>


    <div class="squareColourHF">
    </div>
    <div class="squareColour">
    </div>
    <div class="squareColour">
    </div>
    <div class="squareColourHF">
    </div>
    <div class="squareColourHF">
    </div>


    <div class="squareColour">
    </div>
    <div class="squareColour">
    </div>
    <div class="squareColourHF">
    </div>
    <div class="squareColourHF">
    </div>
    <div class="squareColour">
    </div>


    <div class="squareColour">
    </div>
    <div class="squareColour">
    </div>
    <div class="squareColour">
    </div>
    <div class="squareColour">
    </div>
    <div class="squareColour">
    </div>


    <div class="squareColour">
    </div>
    <div class="squareColour">
    </div>
    <div class="squareColour">
    </div>
    <div class="squareColour">
    </div>
    <div class="squareColour ">
    </div>


    <div class="squareColour">
    </div>
    <div class="squareColour">
    </div>
    <div class="squareColour">
    </div>
    <div class="squareColour">
    </div>
    <div class="squareColour">
    </div>

    <div class="squareColour">
    </div>
    <div class="squareColour ">
    </div>
    <div class="squareColour">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row row7">
    <div class="squareColour">
    </div>
    <div class="squareColour">
    </div>
    <div class="squareColour">
    </div>
    <div class="squareColour">
    </div>
    <div class="squareColour">
    </div>

    <div class="squareColour">
    </div>
    <div class="squareColour">
    </div>
    <div class="squareColour">
    </div>
    <div class="squareColour">
    </div>
    <div class="squareColour">
    </div>


    <div class="squareColour">
    </div>
    <div class="squareColour">
    </div>
    <div class="squareColour">
    </div>
    <div class="squareColour">
    </div>
    <div class="squareColourHF">
    </div>


    <div class="squareColourHF">
    </div>
    <div class="squareColour">
    </div>
    <div class="squareColour">
    </div>
    <div class="squareColourHF">
    </div>
    <div class="squareColourHF">
    </div>


    <div class="squareColour">
    </div>
    <div class="squareColour">
    </div>
    <div class="squareColourHF">
    </div>
    <div class="squareColourHF">
    </div>
    <div class="squareColour">
    </div>


    <div class="squareColour">
    </div>
    <div class="squareColour">
    </div>
    <div class="squareColour">
    </div>
    <div class="squareColour">
    </div>
    <div class="squareColour">
    </div>


    <div class="squareColour">
    </div>
    <div class="squareColour">
    </div>
    <div class="squareColour">
    </div>
    <div class="squareColour">
    </div>
    <div class="squareColour ">
    </div>


    <div class="squareColour">
    </div>
    <div class="squareColour">
    </div>
    <div class="squareColour">
    </div>
    <div class="squareColour">
    </div>
    <div class="squareColour">
    </div>

    <div class="squareColour">
    </div>
    <div class="squareColour ">
    </div>
    <div class="squareColour">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[**Codepen Demo**](http://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/dXVLZo)

Comment: Thank you, I can't up vote cause i dont have 15 karma but thanks so much.